# set different height for tr and td

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a table where the inner vertical borders(of each cell) are not touching the horizontal borders as in this picture;

[image]

To do that i set the borders to be on each tr, so each "line" is separated and i set left border for each cell. Now I'm trying to make the tr longer than the td for the space, but it's not working.
Any ideas on how to set it? Or a different way to achieve the same goal?
It has to be in a table and I can't use grid or flex.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  color: white;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

td {
  background-color: white;
  color: DodgerBlue;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid dodgerblue;
}

.first-col {
  width: 40%;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col">Prodoct code</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>sub total</th>
        <th>remove</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>sub total</td>
        <td>remove</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>sub total</td>
        <td>remove</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>sub total</td>
        <td>remove</td>
      </tr>
  </div>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could fake the illusion with pseudo classes and selectors if you want to keep it as a table, just did the td's to show concept, would need appled to th's also for full effect.

Hope this helps, cheers.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.container{
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 90%;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
    color: white;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    
}
td{ position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    color: DodgerBlue;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  
}
.first-col{
    width: 40%;
} 
tr{
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    height: 100px;
}

td:before, td:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  content: '';
  border: #fff 5px solid;
  margin-right: -1px;
}

td:last-child:before, td:last-child:after {
  margin: 0;
}

td:before {
  top: 0;
}

td:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="first-col">Prodoct code</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>sub total</th>
                        <th>remove</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                            <td>Unit Price</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>sub total</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                            <td>Unit Price</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>sub total</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                            <td>Unit Price</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>sub total</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                    </tr>
    </div>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::before` and `::after` style for `td` to draw the border.
I have removed `border-left` from the `td` style and added below css.

```
td::before{
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;

}
td:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: " ";
    border: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.container{
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 90%;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
    color: white;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    
}
td{
    background-color: white;
    color: DodgerBlue;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* border-left: 1px solid dodgerblue; */
}
td::before{
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;

}
td:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: " ";
    border: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%; 
}
.first-col{
    width: 40%;
} 
tr{
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="first-col">Prodoct code</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>sub total</th>
                        <th>remove</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                            <td>Unit Price</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>sub total</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                            <td>Unit Price</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>sub total</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                            <td>Unit Price</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>sub total</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

You can also test it here.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/k6dc0gq7/

**Edit:**

Without `line-height`..
JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/k6dc0gq7/2/

Enjoy.!

Comment: Updated the snippet and fiddle.. :) Removed the line-height.

Answer (score -1):

See if this works for you.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
    color: white;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    
}
td{
    background-color: white;
    color: DodgerBlue;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    
  
}
   
 .first-col{
        width: 40%;
    } 

tr{
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="first-col">Prodoct code</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Unit Price</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>sub total</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>remove</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>Unit Price</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>sub total</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>remove</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>Unit Price</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>sub total</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>remove</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td class="first-col">Prodoct code</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>Unit Price</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>sub total</td>
                                <td><h1>|</h1></td>
                                <td>remove</td>
                        </tr>
        </div>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  Why does it work? What did you do?

Comment: Run the code snippet.It produced the desired output. I modified the css and just added a '|' after every <td>.

Comment: So - to be clear, I'm just trying to help you succeed with StackOverflow.  My point is: A good answer is descriptive in what it does and how it works.  I know _that_ it works, but some comments or else a description will help _future visitors understand what you've done.

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot bro :-)